# overlaying one block on another css

Tags: html, css

i need to overlaying div to div like this img the gray div should cover the yellow div in the upper right corner
[image]

I tried it like this, but yellow  does not get into the position I need

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-auto-rows: 100px; 
    grid-auto-columns: 100px; */
}

.item-1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 5 / 4;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

.item-1 img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 170px;
}

.item-2 img {
  width: 368px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item-1">
    <img src="img/square.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <img src="img/Rectangle 24.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use lorempicsum for dummy images

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this simply by doing this.
Just place the element you want inside the element you want it to overlap, give it a position absolute and just assign the left/right values.

```css
.box1 {
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 100px;
}

.box2 {
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    right: 120px;
    top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```